# How I can manage child height according to dynamic content in flex box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In this example child2 has dynamic data which can be increase or decrease, and child3 has fixed height. main parent has dynamic window height, so I want child2 will show entirely without having scroll until whole remaining spaced got covered and child1 should cover remaining space with scroll inside.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child1 {
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: blue;
}

.child3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">data</div>
  <div class="child2">dynamic data</div>
  <div class="child3">fixed data</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @Rupinderpal, could you provide an example with sample content so that the overflow scroll shows?

Comment: Also, to simplify your question, could you remove the `flex` properties from the child `div`s? Or is this necessary? I don't see how it relates to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.mainCon{
  height: 390px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.upperBox{
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.remaining{
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 10px;
}
.adjustable{
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: calc(100% - 10px);
}
.fixed{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainCon">
  <div class="upperBox">
    <div class="remaining">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
    </div>
    <div class="adjustable">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fixed">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use Flex:

```css
body{
  background:blue;
  height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
}
.container{
  display:flex;
  background:white;
  height:100%;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.box:nth-of-type(1){
  /* according to remain Space*/
  background:green;
  flex:1 1 auto;
}
.box:nth-of-type(2){
  /* according to inner Content*/
  background:yellow;
  flex:0 1 auto;
}
.box:nth-of-type(3){

  /*fixed Height*/
  background:red;
  flex:0 1 50px;;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <box class="box">according to remain Space</box>
  <box class="box">according to inner Content</box>
  <box class="box">fixed height</box>
</div>
```

Comment: fixed height should be 3rd child, "height according to content" should be 2nd child and "height according to remain part" should be first child

Comment: and same if child1 got overflow content then other child height got affected

Comment: You could just change the number in nth-of-type. but I did it now my self

Answer (score 0):

Is this the desired behavior (you should change the height in .child3 to your desired value):

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child1 {
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
}

.child2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: blue;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.child3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: orange;
  height: 3rem;
}
```